# WMQ as transaction coordinator for Java, DB2 doen't participate in transaction

Tags: java, db2, ibm-mq, distributed-transactions

We are using *Websphere MQ 7.1.1* as a transaction coordinator with *DB2 10.0.1* as one of the resource manager. Both WMQ and DB2 are hosted on different linux machines. Java code is deployed on MQ machine with Binding mode.

I am able to connect to DB2 from MQ machine. I have configured the `qm.ini` for DB2. Problem is DB2 doesn't participate in transaction. We are getting **MQ Exception 2195**.

Please tell me if I have missed any configuration.

Comment: 2195 is MQRC_UNEXPECTED_ERROR. This should be accompanied by an error in your AMQERR01.LOG and perhaps also an FDC. Please check for these and add the details to your question in order to enable us to help you further.

Comment: I am getting rc 2003 on transaction commit. Transaction doesn't rollback after this.